# Почему то InlineKeyboardButtons не отображаются

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, pyrogram

День добрый. Кто знает почему кнопки inlinebuttons не отображаются
Вот код

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup,InlineKeyboardButton

bot_token=''
api_id = 12345
api_hash = ""

bot = Client("my_bot", api_id, api_hash, bot_token)

@bot.on_message(filters.command('start'))
def main(client, message):
    message.reply_text("Hello, I am a Forwarder bot")
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        [[InlineKeyboardButton("Button 1", callback_data='button1'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Button 2", callback_data='button2')]]
    )
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Choose an option:', reply_markup=keyboard)
bot.run()
```